# How to structure Models and Views in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, theory, directory-structure, serverside-javascript, file-structure

I am writing a NodeJS based server- and client-side JavaScript application. I have Controllers, Models, Views and Presenters. The problem I am facing is that some parts of the code need to be only server-side, some client-side and some both.

For example, Controllers are pure server-side thing for me so they should not be available client-side. Presenters, on the other hand, are pure client-side thing so should be available in client-side.

Take a look at my current bad structure:

```
project\
project\public\index.js
project\public\images\
project\protected\controllers\
project\protected\models\
project\protected\views\
project\protected\presenters\
```

The problem I face is that public folder is the document root and protected is outside of the document root. I need to be able to use Views in both client- and server-side. So, my Views can't be in protected. The same applies to models and tons of other things. I need to be able to access them client-side too.

I am starting to think I have to put the entire structure under document root with the exception of some configuration file. Is this what I should do? Are there any problems with this approach? I am asking because most web frameworks (Django, Zend Framework) work the way that the framework is outside of the document root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[My github structure](https://github.com/Raynos/raynos-blog) (out-dated)

```
-- Main level
project\
-- Your main app. Keep light
project\app.js
-- All your configuration, development/production setups
project\app-configure
-- Your server-side controllers/routing. Keep light
project\controllers\
-- Any WebSocket specific code.
project\socket-io\
-- Server side test
project\test\
-- Your public folder. Client side can access these files.   
-- Serve this folder as static content
project\public\
-- I keep my backbone collections here. Used on both server & client
project\public\collections
-- public css files
project\public\css
-- public js files. Including a main.js to bootstrap the router
project\public\js
-- public models used on both server & client.
project\public\models
-- client side router, used to router hashbang urls. Can use same routing
-- logic as the server. This is virtually a second set of controllers around
-- All your models
project\public\routers\
-- public tests. QUnit based
project\public\test\
-- View files
project\public\views
-- Templates used to render HTML. Used on client & server
project\public\views\templates
-- Backbone view files. Used to code up interaction, and business logic
-- This uses templates to render HTML and DOM events to handle interaction
project\public\views\backbone-views
```

This is based on [express](http://expressjs.com/) and [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). Controllers are [express-controllers](https://github.com/drudge/express-controllers/) public\routers are client-side routing using [davis](http://davisjs.com/)

Basically because the MVC is so heavily re-used across client and server, the only thing that's not public are server-side tests and the server-side controllers. As well as the configuration settings and any socket-io based code.

My advice is simple anything that's used in both goes in `\public\`

Because MVC re-use on both the client and the server is a new thing, there aren't any examples you can look at. Apart from hunting for big open source node.js websites on github.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I suppose one could also put controllers, tests and the rest in public too as long as configuration/keys/passwords stay out. It makes me feel more confused if views, models, presenters are in public but controllers are one step down. I know that is based on logical decision, but it feels cluttered. Do you think there are down sides to put everything in public considering that the code is all compiled into garbage for production and that configuration with potential keys/passwords are protected?

Comment: @rFactor There's no need to place server-side only code in public. The client-side is open source. Clientside javascript can not be hidden / closed-source. You have no choice. Added more detail to file structure. And yes keys/passwords etc are not in public.

Comment: @Raynos -- is there a reason you use Davis instead of Backbone routers?

Comment: @Tauren davis has a nicer API. And I don't like backbone. The entire answer is completely outdated.